# How to reinitialize UserState with new blobstorage outside Startup.cs class?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework, persistent-storage

I have a front end webchat channel, I am sending an event activity which has a value(storage container name) to be sent on `OnEventActivityAsync` handler. How can I reconfigure the `UserState` initialized in startup.cs with a new storage name that I received from the event?

I am familiar with a concept of initializing `UserState` and `AzureBlobStorage` in **Startup.cs** but here I need to change the container name when `OnEventActivityAsync` is hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official procedure to rename the container name out of the Startup.cs. But we have a small procedure to check regarding **`OnEventActivityAsync`** activity. Check out the links mentioned below to checkout the nearest procedure.

Link1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.activityhandler?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

Link2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.activityhandler.oneventactivityasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#microsoft-bot-builder-activityhandler-oneventactivityasync(microsoft-bot-builder-iturncontext((microsoft-bot-schema-ieventactivity))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)

Comment: Yes Sairam, I get it thanks.